# When to use acquireTokenByRefreshToken vs. acquireToken

Tags: java, adal, adal4j

When and why would I use the "refresh" forms of the [AuthenticationContext](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationContext.java) `acquireToken` methods, vs. just calling the initial forms with the same credentials again?

Answer (score 0):

I guess one answer would be that a refresh token can last a lot longer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens

> Access Tokens are short-lived and must be refreshed after they expire
>   to continue accessing resources. You can refresh the access_token by
>   submitting another POST request to the /token endpoint, but this time
>   providing the refresh_token instead of the code.
>
> Refresh tokens do not have specified lifetimes. Typically, the
>   lifetimes of refresh tokens are relatively long. However, in some
>   cases, refresh tokens expire, are revoked, or lack sufficient
>   privileges for the desired action. Your application needs to expect
>   and handle errors returned by the token issuance endpoint correctly.